# JQuery: Best way to bind events to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Consider the following:

```
var template = '<div class="dynamic">Some markup</div>'
  , $template = $(template);
$template.on('click.namespace.data-api', function(e) { doStuff() });
$('div.#parent').append($template);
```

To me, this seems to be the most optimal way to bind an event to a node, since the event is attached to a node that has already been introduced as a jQuery object. However, I'm not sure how this plays out during actual click events; on click, is jQuery able to find this element immediately since the event is bound to a jQuery object? Or is it more optimal to bind the event using something like:

```
var template = '<div class="dynamic">Some markup</div>'
  , $template = $(template);
$('div.#parent').append($template);
$('div.#parent').on('click.namespace.data-api', 'div.dynamic', function(e) { doStuff() });
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're asking, since these code snippets do different things.  The first is creating a new element and adding it to the page, which the second doesn't do.  These also add click handlers to different elements (though presumably with the same observed effect?).  It's not clear to me what you're comparing between the two or why.

Comment: jQuery supports binding click event listeners via `.on()` to document fragment (which is your `$template`) in this case, even though it is not injected into the DOM yet: https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/548

Comment: @David, I've updated for clarity. In the second example I'm adding the handler onto the parent node which listens for clicks on the `div.dynamic` child node.

Comment: @Terry, very interesting. Is binding event listeners to document fragment as efficient, or more, than other methods of event binding in jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

JQuery objects only persist in the exact call they are in. As soon as that call is done the object no longer is related as a JQuery object.

As you are showing with click delegation you wont have to worry about the dynamic aspect of the element being created at any moment, because the handler is hooked to the parent node, then watches for click on the delegated element/class.

Writing the second version of click delegation using the direct delegation method to me is much easier to read, and is more clear when you come back to read again in the future.

Comment: While you may personally prefer vanilla JavaScript, it would seem that the question is asking about jQuery.  It's not really clear what the rest of your answer is addressing in the question.

Comment: David - That was my mistake, I read the 2nd use as if $("div#parent").click("on", "delegation") was used.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of binding event to the specific element, you can bind it to document instead.

```
`$('.dynamic').click()` can be replaced with `$(document).on('click', '.dynamic', function())`
```

Comment: The code in the question is already using event delegation.  The careful observer will see that there is no call to the `.click()` function.

Comment: Also, it is not advisable to attach event listeners to `document`, because jQuery will have to compare the event to all elements in the path of bubbling up, which degrades performance significantly.